# Rails 3 - how to write the block of code in HAML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

From ERB I have this part of code, that works me well:

```
$('#id_eleme').append('<div id="form_data"><%=form_tag(articles_path) do%>
                         <div id="' + article.name+ '" style="width:330px;">
                           ...some static text
                         </div>
                       <%end%></div>');
```

I converted my project to HAML, but I don't know, how should look this part of code correctly in HAML notation... **article.name** is a variable from javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

```
:javascript
   $('#id_eleme').append("<div id='form_data'>#{form_tag(articles_path) }
    <div id='#{article.name}' style='width:330px;'>
      ...some static text
    </div>
  </div>");
```